# question about stem cells

Tags: stem-cells

I was reading this paper:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26119455

and became confused after this sentence:

"The  ICM-derived mouse embryonic  stem  (ES)  cells and epiblast-derived
human  embryonic  stem  cells have  the  full  potential  to 
differentiate  to  ectoderm, mesoderm,  endoderm, and trophoblast."

As far as I know, the trophoblast is originated from morula cells that are totipotent, and ICM cells are pluripotent...

Moreover, are ESCs derived from the ICM of the blastocyst? Because if yes, does it mean that they can also become primitive endoderm and give rise to some extraembryonic tissues? Because as I know only epiblast (primitive ectoderm) gives rise to 3 germ layers... does it mean that ESC are derived from epiblast only or not?

Thanks